# Как повысить скорость нахождения определённый цвета пикселя на скриншоте?

Tags: python, изображения, циклы, производительность

Имеется небольшой код, **задача** которого **найти определённый цвет пикселя** на скриншоте. Ну вот вопрос. **Как можно повысить быстродействие** этой программы? Миллион итераций - это ой как не профессионально))

```
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw
import pyautogui
while True:
        image = pyautogui.screenshot (region = (700,100, 850, 900))
        for x in range(image.size[0]):
            for y in range(image.size[1]):    
                if image.getpixel((x, y))[0]==164:
                   print("Я нашёл!")
```

Я попытался увеличить производительность экрана, уменьшив размер скриншота, зная, что пиксель появляется именно в этой области. Может это можно сделать вообще с помощью какой-то библиотеки? (Numpy?)

Comment: Попробуйте использовать numpy, вот тут есть пример в одном ответе https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44923141/find-pixels-with-given-rgb-colors

Comment: Не по теме вопроса, но если вас сильно волнует скорость, то, возможно для создания скриншотов вместо pyautogui лучше взять [mss](https://pypi.org/project/mss/) (интеграция с numpy в нём тоже есть)